# Hivemq loading default config, Problems with configuration.properties

Tags: hivemq

I am new to hivemq.In the hivemq conf folder there is config.xml
But in documentation there are various files like configuration.properties or application.properties.Those are not in the folder.

When I tried to create it, hivemq gives an error that Configuration is not found. If I don't want to go for XML can I configure it through configuration.properties file? So what is the right way to configure through configuration.properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HiveMQ 3 uses a XML based configuration, see http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/latest/#configuration-chapter

It's not possible to use a properties file based configuration. In case you found some old examples where the old properties based configuration is used, best would be to report it to the HiveMQ support so they can fix it.